# Retrieve each <div> of an html file on one line

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div id="div_1">
    <p class="keywords">
        <strong> Those are the main keywords </strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Decentralization</li>
            <li>Planning</li>
        </ol>
    </p> 
</div>
<div id="div_2">
<p class="keywords">
    <strong>This is the first paragraph of the second div </strong>
    <strong>This is the second paragraph of the second div </strong>
</p> 
</div>
<div id="div_3">
<p> This is the first paragraph of the second div </p> 
</div>
```

I want to parse this html file so that I have each div in a line, which means this output:

```
Those are the main keywords Decentralization Planning
This is the first paragraph of the second div This is the second paragraph of the second div
This is the first paragraph of the third div
```

This is my code :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup (open(document, encoding = "utf8"), "html.parser")
myDivs = soup.findAll("div", id = re.compile("^div_"))
for div in myDivs:
    txt = div.text + "\n"
    print (txt)
```

This returns to me the text of the < div > but with each of its tags (< p >, < i > ) in a line

Any idea how I may do that?

Answer (score 0):

*Yap run for loop on `div` > `P`*

*https://jsfiddle.net/0m3r_/e7Loa96z/1/*

```html
<html>
 <head></head>
  <body>
   <div id="div_1">
    <p class="keywords">
     <strong> Those are the main keywords </strong>
     <ol>
      <li>Decentralization</li>
      <li>Planning</li>
     </ol>
    </p> 
   </div>
   
   
   <div id="div_2">
    <p class="keywords">
     <strong>This is the first paragraph of the second div </strong>
     <strong>This is the second paragraph of the second div </strong>
    </p> 
   </div>
   
   <div id="div_3">
    <p> This is the first paragraph of the second div </p> 
   </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = r"D:\Temp\example.html"

with open(url, "r") as page:
    contents = page.read()
    html = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'html.parser')

    html_body = html.find('body')
    elements = html.find_all('div')

    for div in elements:
        p = div.find_all('p')
        text = [i.text for i in p]
        print(text)
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div id="div_1">
    <p class="keywords">
        <strong> Those are the main keywords </strong>
        <ol>
            <li>Decentralization</li>
            <li>Planning</li>
        </ol>
    </p> 
</div>
<div id="div_2">
<p class="keywords">
    <strong>This is the first paragraph of the second div </strong>
    <strong>This is the second paragraph of the second div </strong>
</p> 
</div>
<div id="div_3">
<p> This is the first paragraph of the second div </p> 
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.findAll("div", id=re.compile("^div_")):
    target = [a.get_text(strip=True, separator=" ") for a in item.findAll("p")]
    print(*target)
```

Output:

```
Those are the main keywords Decentralization Planning
This is the first paragraph of the second div This is the second paragraph of the second div
This is the first paragraph of the second div
```

Comment: @ahmed Is there a way to retrieve all the tags inside the div and not just <p> ? since i'm working on multiple files each one of them its own structure. Something more like this in Java : text = text + "\n" + div.text() ; but with python.

Comment: @user93804 I've provided an answer according to the question being asked.